# Is it possible to integrate custom backend server with Magento?

Tags: magento, integration, backend

We have our own custom backend implementation(Java) with database to store the seller and store information. We dont have a implementation yet for the ecommerce solution.

We want to use Magento to provide ecommerce solution.
Is it possible to integrate our custom backend with Magento?

It will be very helpful if you could share some ideas or suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea about this but I think, but I think the below link will be helpful for you.,
https://www.mage-world.com/blog/create-a-module-with-custom-database-table-in-magento-2.html
If your problem is still not cleared message me on instagram. id:harsith_sivanandham

I am happy to help you

Comment: The link shows creation of a custom DB table. I am afraid this will not solve my requirement.